# JS animation seemingly not reset when style.animation is replaced

Tags: javascript, css, animation, opacity

I have two `<span>` in some HTML code along with the following JS script :

```
for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    document.head.prepend(document.createElement("style"))
}
const duration = 5
const set_animation = (view_index, submenu, opacity_end) => {
    const opacity_start = window.getComputedStyle(submenu).getPropertyValue("opacity")
    document.head.querySelectorAll("style")[view_index].innerHTML = `@keyframes anim${view_index} {0% {opacity: ${opacity_start}} 100% {opacity: ${opacity_end}}}}`
    submenu.style.animation = `anim${view_index} ${Math.abs(opacity_end - opacity_start) * duration}s forwards`
}
let i = 0
document.querySelectorAll(".submenu").forEach((submenu) => {
    let i_ = i
    submenu.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
        console.log("enter", i_)
        set_animation(i_, submenu, 0)
    })
    submenu.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
        console.log("leave", i_)
        set_animation(i_, submenu, 1)
    })
    i++
})
```

**When the mouse enter a `<span.submenu>`, an animation supposed to slowly lower its opacity down to 0 is added to it and when the mouse leave it, an animation supposed to slowly raise its opacity up to 1 is added to it.**

In practice, the first enter seems to work just fine, but when I leave the component, its opacity is (at least visually) set back to 1 and when reentering it, it's like the timer was still running in the background and the opacity is instantly set back to the percentage of the time elapsed between now and when the first timer was initially started.

Why does this happen and how can I achieve the expected behavior I just explained ?

In case you're wondering, I couldn't achieve this using `CSS:hover` because this is simpler version of my code, in the real one the fading behavior of the span is triggered by the mouse entering and leaving one of it's container.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with a much simpler solution thanks to mister GPT:

```
.submenu {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.tab:hover .submenu {
    opacity: 1;
}
```